# Llama 70b on Hugging Face Inference API Endpoint short responses

Tags: python, huggingface, llama

I just deployed the Nous-Hermes-Llama2-70b parameter on a 2x Nvidia A100 GPU through the Hugging Face Inference endpoints.

When I tried the following code, the response generations were incomplete sentences that were less than 1 line long.

```
import requests

API_URL = 'https://myendpoint.us-east-1.aws.endpoints.huggingface.cloud'
headers = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer mytoken1234",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

def query(payload):
  response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json=payload)
  return response.json()
 
output = query({
  "inputs": "### Instruction:\r\nCome up with a joke about cats\r\n### Response:\r\n",
})
```

The output in this case was:

```
"Why don't cats play poker in the jungle?

 Because "
```

As you see, the response stopped after 9 words.

Do I need to add more headers to the request like temperature and max token length? How would I do that? What do I need to do to get normal, long responses?

Here is the model I'm using: https://huggingface.co/NousResearch/Nous-Hermes-Llama2-70b

Comment: With most generative AI, you can either wait a long time for the full generation to complete and get the full result back (which is atrociously slow if it's a lot of text), or you can stream the results in in realtime as they are completed; in this case I'm not sure if the Hugging Face Inference endpoints need to be treated specially in order to stream the result back in realtime, but given how things are behaving, that certainly seems like the case. I highly recommend looking at other examples, and determining how to check if the API is meant to be streaming the results back or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added "max_new_tokens" => 256 as a parameter, fixed it.